# DataTable remove columns and re-order the columns

Tags: c#, linq, datatable, datacolumn, reorderlist

I want to remove unwanted columns from a datatable and arrange the order of the columns in pre-defined order

For example, my table columns are like below,

```
 Col2|Col1|Col3|Test|Test1|Col5|Col4|Some col name|Col6
```

I want to remove Test, Test1 and Some col name and reorder by datatable into below format

```
Col1|Col2|Col3|Col4|Col5|Col6

// I need the below columns
List<string> tableColumns = new List<string>();
tableColumns.Add("Col1");
tableColumns.Add("Col2");
tableColumns.Add("Col3");
tableColumns.Add("Col4");
tableColumns.Add("Col5");
tableColumns.Add("Col6");

List<DataColumn> tblColumns = MyDataTable.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().ToList();

//Remove unwanted columns
foreach (DataColumn col in tblColumns)
{
  if (!tableColumns.Contains(col.ColumnName.Trim()))
  {
   MyDataTable.Columns.Remove(col);
  }
}
```

Now how do I re-order the columns in the below order?

```
Col1|Col2|Col3|Col4|Col5|Col6
```

I tried like in the below code, but it fails if all items in tableColumns doesn’t exists in datatable.
Also some times data table column name has some empty space (ex “  Col1”)

```
foreach (var col in tableColumns)
{

     MyDataTable.Columns[col].SetOrdinal(tableColumns.IndexOf(col));

}
```

Which is the best way to remove unwanted columns and re-arrange the columns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you remove the unwanted columns, here is how you can order them:

```
int index = 0;

foreach (var col in
    MyDataTable.Columns
    .Cast<DataColumn>()
    .OrderBy(x => tableColumns.IndexOf(x.ColumnName))
    .ToList())
{
    col.SetOrdinal(index);
    index ++;
}
```

This selects the columns from the `DataTable`, and orders them by their corresponding index in the `tableColumns` list.

Then it invokes `SetOrdinal` on each one of them, incrementing the index each time.

Answer (score 0):

I think your columns may have random order like Col2,Col1,Col3. And you want to rearrange and remove the unwanted columns, like Col1,Col2,Col3.

```
string[] srr = new string[]{"Col2","Col1","Col3","Test","Test1","Col6","Col4","Some col name","Col5"};

DataTable MyDataTable = new DataTable();

foreach(string col in srr)
{
    MyDataTable.Columns.Add(col);               
}

List<string> arrayNames = (from DataColumn x in MyDataTable.Columns
                      select x.ColumnName).ToList();

foreach(var col in arrayNames)
{
    if(!col.Contains("Col"))
    {
        MyDataTable.Columns.Remove(col);            
    }
    else
    {
        int result = Convert.ToInt32(Regex.Match(col.ToString(), @"\d+$").Value);
        MyDataTable.Columns[col].SetOrdinal(result-1);          
    }
}
```

This will remove the columns like Test,Test1,some col name ie. columns which don't have the word "Col" (change the logic according to your program). Then by using regex it will extract the numbers from column names. ie 1 from "Col1", then rearrange the columns according to it.